# Can Savannah be stalled with agressive yoke pull?

Tags: flight-controls, flight-training, stall

My friend fly ultra light Savannah, 2 seats plane,wings dont have slats ,it has vortex generators at leading edge.

He says that he cant stall plane with agressive yoke pull (I talk about speeds above stall-speed).

My question is this really true,why airflow dont separate from wing at high AoA and cause reduction in lift and sudden drop in altitude when pull yoke as fast you could?

He says plane just starts climb an that is what happend.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is this really true,why airflow dont separate from wing at high AoA and cause reduction in lift and sudden drop in altitude when pull yoke as fast you could?

I will try to answer this explicitely stated question in more generic terms.

As already mentioned, a wing will stall when AoA increases above particular value. This is true regardless airplane, wing profile or anything else. Particular angle and particular lift/drag curves in stalled region of course depends.

First think to keep on mind is: **Angle of attack is measured relative to the airflow.** Assuming no wind, no thermal lift or other airmass movement, it will be the angle between wing chord and direction of airplane movement. So in a climb the angle between horizon and wing chord will be higher (for same given AoA). During a rapid descent wing chord can point below horizon and it will be still positive AoA generating lift as usual.

So, there are generally two (three) things which can happen when you suddenly pull on a stick in horizontal flight:

1. If you pull softly enough, the plane is light, does not have enough elevator authority and/or has powerful engine ... then ... as soon as AoA starts to increase, the lift will increase too above weight of the plane. This leads to extra vertical force accelerating you upwards. Gaining vertical velocity, the AoA (for same pitch) decreases somewhat.

   Initial horizontal flight. AoA as necessary to generate lift equal to weight.
   [image: Horizontal flight]

   First consequence of the stick input is pitching up.
   [image: Pitch up]
   But the increased AoA results immediately in excessive lift from main wings (higher then weight) and as a consequence the plane starts to *accelerate* upwards (any net resulting force = acceleration).

   As it builds up vertical speed relative wind starts to turn (it has always direction against the actual motion) and decrease AoA.
   [image: Climbing]
   Steady climb would be reached when increase in pitch equals increase in vertical velocity, so effective AoA is back at original 1g-level. (*Note: for simplicity, I am omitting from images change in direction of lift force with pitch. It does not change anything principal here except adding a drag which needs to be overcome by propeller -- energy necessary for climbing.*)

   So, if the nose pitch is increasing slower than you are gaining vertical speed, you will overgo into climb without stalling wings. Because this is exactly a standard way to initiate a climb, it *has to* be possible to perform with appropriate stick input without stalling.

   (Would you continue pulling on the stick, you will eventually lose airspeed because of engine power limit, get out of the elevator authority or eventually complete a looping. :) But this happens only later.)
2. If you pull abruptly, but elevator is small, you can actually stall the elevator. That is, you will still get some nose-up input, but it will be limited not by the stick movement, but the maximal force/torque elevator can provide. In practice the result will be same as in the previous point.
3. If the pull is sudden enough and elevator has enough authority to pitch up nose faster than airplane can gain vertical speed, you can exceed stall AoA before initiating a climb. Then wings will stall in horizontal flight.

   For reasonable speed and common airplane, it can be well impossible to do this and only result will be either #1 or #2. OTOH this is exactly how you fly [snap (flick) roll](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2014/september/flight-training-magazine/technique--snap-rolls) in an aerobatic plane, so with big enough control surfaces you can definitively induce stall from horizontal flight in moderate speed range.

**Note below**: it is good to keep on mind that "stall" does not mean "airplane is going to crash". Airfoil stall (any airfoil can stall, not only main wing, but usually people implicitly means main wing) is an angle of attack where the lift (for given airspeed) starts to decrease with further increasing AoA.

Just this, nothing else. It *does not* mean zero lift. If *does not* mean crash. It even does not need to mean significantly less lift (depending on particular airfoil). The fact that AoA versus lift dependency is inverted makes airplane behavior quite contra-intuitive – for example aileron inputs will have practically opposite effect than usual (which can in turn easily lead to crash), or a stability is lost, but there is still lot airplanes which can fly seemingly quite "normally" even with main wing stalled.

Comment: **Gaining vertical velocity, the AoA (for same pitch) decreases somehow**This part I dont understand.Plane is not going up as whole like helicopter.Plane is  climbing in straight line ,so where vertical airflow velocity comes from? When plane climb his pitch angle must be greater then when fly in horizontal flight,but plane still travel in straight line so dont feel vertical airflow velocity.

Comment: @EBV821 *somewhat* not *somehow*, of course, pardon my English. Anyway, yes, it is not purely vertical movement, but there is still non-zero vertical component and therefore relative wind has to be oriented partially from above too. If pitch with respect to ground/horizon/inertial reference does not increase further, an increase in vertical speed means lower AoA. I have tried to sketch some illustration, not sure if it helps. :)

Comment: Actually, in the first approximation, for given airspeed, there is only one possible AoA (two if you count stalled region too) for steady balanced flight (straight, either horizontal or climbing/sinking, but not turn). Any different angle will result in excessive force in some direction (lift or gravity) resulting in imbalance. When the flight stabilizes again in new regime, the AoA has to be back at value for 1g-lift.

Comment: Indeed your second picture(pitch up when still going horizontaly) is my topic question:But from your answer I see that it is very hard to stall plane like that.That means my friend was right.

Comment: **If pitch with respect to ground/horizon/inertial reference does not increase further, an increase in vertical speed means lower AoA** Again I dont understand what you want to say.There is no climb if you dont increase pitch angle compare to horizontal pitch angle.So you must pull joke ,lift your nose to climb.But then when you are climbing,thurst from propeler produce additional lift so plane fly with reduce AoA to keep gravity in balance.AoA is not reduced because of vertical induce flow ,because vertical  flow dont exist if plane fly up in straight line...

Comment: It is not a propeller what initiates climb, it is an excessive lift from main wing because of increased AoA. (the propeller is there only to prevent losing energy/speed; any glider can go from horizontal flight into the climb in exactly same way as a powered plane). And because excessive AoA means *acceleration* upwards, in steady climb forces needs to be in equilibrium and AoA at 1g level.

Comment: **And because excessive AoA means acceleration upwards, in steady climb forces needs to be in equilibrium and AoA at 1g level**  When initiate climb,when pull yoke plane is going up in curved path(not straight line) ,lift from wing act as  centripetal force which force plane  to go in  curved path and relative airflow is tangential to that curved path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117744/discussion-between-martin-and-ebv821).

Answer (score 3):

I have 500 hours in one, more or less... This one:

[image]

In my experience, if –with the engine at cruise, say 2/3 power– you start pulling the stick slowly, the machine does obediently pitch up, with no stall, but one has to be careful, and fast with the pedals. At the extreme, the airplane is pointing more or less to the zenith, and starts falling tail first while rolling, in reaction to the prop's torque. But it doesn't stall...

If you try the same gliding with the engine at idle, you won't be able to avoid a wing dropping down, more or less when the pitch reaches 30--40º...

Comment: Is this normal behavior for every plane that you cant stall plane with agressive yoke pull?So only way to force plane to stall is to fly below stall-speed?

Comment: Stall speed is the airspeed at which, for a given load, you have to increase the AoA to the critical in order to get just enough lift as to stay in s/l flight. Speed, by itself, has nothing to do with the stall, this being related with and determined by the AoA. Concerning the 'aggressive yoke pull', you should start by defining that properly...

Comment: marvelous photo and good information! I hope this behaviour is communicated to you by the designers/manufacturers. Are you saying it is difficult to stall it without a wing drop, or that it directly goes into an incipient spin?

Comment: @xxavier in video he say that stall can happend at any speed.How can initiate stall with  pulling yoke at  higher speeds (speeds above stall-speed) ? My firend say you cant  force Savanah to stall like that,so why this man say that stall can happend at any speed?..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vdnO-1I6Vs&ab_channel=JimAlsip

Comment: @EBV821  And he's right... Stall can happen at **any** speed. You only need to have a big enough AoA. It depends on the airfoil, but it's around 18º for most airfoils. The Savannah (and many STOL planes) can stay aloft with stalled wings, but the aircraft itself stays under control. In most airplanes, a stalled wing means a loss of control and a crash may ensue...

Comment: @skipper44 That's my experience of the tests I've done... The Savannah POH says nothing about the subject...  The maneuver is not risky, because it's a good-natured plane. It does not enter a spin, even if a wing drops, and control is easy to recover.

Comment: @xxavier **And he's right... Stall can happen at any speed.** On other planes if I pull yoke too fast,plane will stall?

Comment: @EBV821 Pulling fast or slow doesn't make much difference. The important magnitude is the angle of attack of the wing. When above the critical value, the wing stalls...

Comment: You make an airplane stall proof by limiting tail power. This is what made the Ercoupe "stall proof". The Savannah, being a Zenith 701 copy with the slats removed, also replaced the 701's heavily cambered tail with the 601's symmetrical tail, giving it less tail power at low speed.  It can't full stall because the tail can't get the wing to stalling AOA, and the VGs make the stall extremely progressive as well as increasing max AOA that can be attained, so there is a large margin between initiation and completion of the stall.  You could get a stall break out of it if you made the tail bigger.